# How to edit the PHPUnit library path in Zend Studio?

Tags: php, environment-variables, zend-studio

I'm trying to set up Zend Studio so I can use PHPUnit, but I can't figure it out. The PHPUnit library path is un-editable.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

This link helped me out.

Right click on your project, then click "Properties". Under "PHP include path", you will find under the "libraries" tab the definition for PHPUnit. Remove that, or edit the path